# find_all only scrapes the last values

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I'm having trouble with my code. It should list all the usernames and time values but it only display last values.
My code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

link = 'https://namemc.com/minecraft-names?sort=asc&length_op=&length=3&lang=&searches=500'

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/89.0.4389.90 Safari/537.36'
}

html_text = requests.get(link,headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_text.text,'lxml')

users = soup.find_all('div', class_='col col-lg order-lg-1 text-nowrap text-ellipsis')
for user in users:
    name = user.find('a').text

dates = soup.find_all('div', class_='col-12 col-lg-5 order-lg-2 text-lg-center')
for time in dates:
    date = time.find('time')


print(name)
print(date)
```

Comment: I'd suggest fixing your indentation and move those `print` statements to the respective `for loops`. Or take a tutorial on how to print the results of an iteration.

Answer (score 1):

This should do it. Make sure your `BeautifulSoup` version is equal to or higher than `4.7.0` in order for the script to fetch the desired content as I used `:has()` pseudo selector within the script. [This](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors) is where you should find more info.

```
import json
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

link = 'https://namemc.com/minecraft-names?sort=asc&length_op=&length=3&lang=&searches=500'

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/89.0.4389.90 Safari/537.36'
}

data = []

html_text = requests.get(link,headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_text.text,'lxml')
for item in soup.select(".card-body > .no-gutters:has(time[datetime])"):
    d = {}
    d['Title'] = item.select_one("a[href^='/name/']").get_text(strip=True)
    d['Date'] = item.select_one("time[datetime]").get_text(strip=True)
    data.append(d)

print(json.dumps(data,indent=4))
```

Output (truncated):

```
[
    {
        "Title": "Commander",
        "Date": "2021-03-19T13:10:40.000Z"
    },
    {
        "Title": "Tigre",
        "Date": "2021-03-19T14:06:17.000Z"
    },
    {
        "Title": "Clear",
        "Date": "2021-03-22T17:06:03.000Z"
    },
    {
        "Title": "cuddles",
        "Date": "2021-03-22T17:30:42.000Z"
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because you overwriting the name variable in every iteration and hence only get the list one. One way around it is to maintain a list of names and dates.

### List Approach

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

link = 'https://namemc.com/minecraft-names?sort=asc&length_op=&length=3&lang=&searches=500'

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/89.0.4389.90 Safari/537.36'
}

html_text = requests.get(link,headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_text.text,'lxml')

names = []
_dates = []

users = soup.find_all('div', class_='col col-lg order-lg-1 text-nowrap text-ellipsis')
for user in users:
    names.append(user.find('a').text)

dates = soup.find_all('div', class_='col-12 col-lg-5 order-lg-2 text-lg-center')
for time in dates:
    _dates.append(time.find('time'))
```

If you only want to print the names a more memory-efficient approach would be to print them on the go.

### Dictionary Approach

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

link = 'https://namemc.com/minecraft-names?sort=asc&length_op=&length=3&lang=&searches=500'

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/89.0.4389.90 Safari/537.36'
}

html_text = requests.get(link,headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_text.text,'lxml')

name_to_date = {}

users = soup.find_all('div', class_='col col-lg order-lg-1 text-nowrap text-ellipsis')
dates = soup.find_all('div', class_='col-12 col-lg-5 order-lg-2 text-lg-center')

for user, time in zip(users, dates):
    name_to_date[user.find('a').text] =time.find('time')
```